# Is there a method to detect and display changes to an HTML file on the Internet?

Tags: java, c++, html, windows, feed

What I'm looking for is a program to detect changes in an HTML file, and display the change on a computer. My goal is to be notified from a changing feed that is in HTML format. An executable C++ program is preferred, yet Java, or any other works as well.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Do you want to implement it, or are you OK with using a service that already exists?

Comment: A program (free preferably). I do not want to use a 3rd party service.

Comment: I think you'll have to rely on a 3rd party service like changedetection.com or you'll have to implement something yourself. To compare html I used the daisydiff library, and can recommend it..

Comment: I downloaded the daisydiff zip folder and tried to run the JAR file, but it won't open. (Windows XP Professional)

Comment: daisydiff is a library you can use in a program you write yourself. It compares html pages, but it's not a GUI program itself, it provides an API to use...

Comment: Oh. If you have created a program that does what i'm asking for using daisydiff, please tell me where to find it. Or if you know of someone who has created the program, please tell me how to contact him. I don't really have the time to write a whole program from scratch right now.

Comment: I haven't written a program, my code is used as a plugin for a custom built editorial team collaboration software. You're on a programmers site here, and should be asking programming questions. I can recommend you to use changedetection.com - I am not affiliated with them, but am a very satisfied user of their free service.

Comment: Alright, I looked at changedetection.com, and that did it for me! Thank you for your help. Have a Good Night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at [changedetection.com](http://www.changedetection.com/) (as referenced by [jlordo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749753/jlordo)) and it now works perfect for what I need. This answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Yahoo Pipes XPath Fetch Page](http://carlo.zottmann.org/2007/09/17/yahoo-pipes-tutorial-how-to-process-html-pages/) + feed reader

Comment: How do I use Yahoo Pipes to do what i'm looking for? I do not have a Yahoo account, and I would like to verify the method to get it to work before I get one. Is there a google, or other major company equivalent?